# DataProtectionScope when using ProtectedData.Protect

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, scope

For encryption/decryption of data which is written in txt files I try to use `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect` and `Unprotect` methods. One of the parameters of these methods is `DataProtectionScope`. For example:

```
byte[] encryptedData = ProtectedData.Protect(data, addEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
...
byte[] decryptedData = ProtectedData.Unprotect(data, addEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

or

```
byte[] encryptedData = ProtectedData.Protect(data, addEntropy, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
...
byte[] decryptedData = ProtectedData.Unprotect(data, addEntropy, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
```

My question is about differences between `CurrentUser` and `LocalMachine` DataProtectionScopes.
Is `LocalMachine` DataProtectionScope just less restrictive than `CurrentUser` one, and difference is, that data, encrypted by any user, can be decrypted by any other user working at the same computer? Or maybe there are some additional specifics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CurrentUser scope stores the encryption keys that only the currently logged user will be able to retrieve the data. On the other hand, LocalMachine scope allows any account on the same computer to access the files but denies remote access. Which one to use depends on your needs.